# Python 3 Boto Error list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

My script asks the user to enter a list of AWS instance IDs. Then print out info about the instances, then terminate them.

But I get this error when I run my script:

```
    File ".\aws_ec2_terminate_instances.py", line 15, in <module>
    name = instance['Tags'][{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': instance_id}]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

This is the code:

```
import sys
import boto3
import collections
from collections import defaultdict

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
instance_id_list = input("Enter an instance ID separated by commas: ")
instance_ids = instance_id_list.split(",")
print("Deleting Instance IDs:")
for instance_id in instance_ids:
    print(instance_id)
    instance = ec2.describe_instances(
        InstanceIds=[instance_id]
        )['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]
    name = instance['Tags'][{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': instance_id}]
    ec2info = defaultdict()
    # Add instance info to a dictionary
    print(instance.get('Instances'))
    ec2info[instance.id] = {
        'Name': name,
        'Instance ID': instance.id,
        'Type': instance.instance_type,
        'State': instance.state['Name'],
        'Private IP': instance.private_ip_address,
        'Public IP': instance.public_ip_address,
        'Launch Time': instance.launch_time
        }
attributes = ['Instance ID', 'Type',
              'State', 'Private IP', 'Public IP', 'Launch Time']
for instance_id, instance in ec2info.items():
    for key in attributes:
        print("{0}: {1}".format(key, instance[key]))
        print("------")
        print("Terminating the instance:")
        ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=instance).stop()
        ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=instance).terminate()
```

How can I get passed this error?

Comment: `print(instance)`, what exactly does instance contain? :) Obviously the value in there is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: Ok thanks. Let me try that. Bet you're right! :)

Comment: I get a json dump with all the info about the instance when I run that print(instance) statement: https://pastebin.com/1Fd1iyqn

Comment: So how do I parse that using python? :)

Comment: `instance['tags'][0]['Value']` should work.

Comment: Ok, progress. I have a new error: KeyError: 'tags'
The current code is here: https://pastebin.com/8uKjenHD

Comment: I changed 'tags' to 'Tags' (based on the json output), I get another error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id'`. Which is strange because I am trying to use defaultdict to print the information: https://pastebin.com/vgTPCCnF

Comment: I think you should stop just throwing "solutions" to the problem, and understand what and why you're doing the things you're doing. That's just a tip, you don't have to take it or listen to it. But I strongly advice you to do so. And yes, sorry. I meant to write `Tags` not `tags`. Keywords to look up: `python dictionary`

Comment: I am trying to understand what and why I am doing the things I am doing.

Comment: Well, I tried googling how to use [defaultdict](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/using-defaultdict-python) in python. I'll look up generally how to use dictionaries in python next. I know I need a better grasp of that subject. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was able to get this working. These are the lines that worked, in case you are interested: `tags = instance['Tags']
    name = ""
    for tag in tags:
        if tag["Key"] == "Name":
            name = tag["Value"]
    print("Name = ", name)`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with the following code:

```
import boto3
import collections
from collections import defaultdict

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
instance_id_list = input("Enter an instance ID separated by commas: ")
instance_ids = instance_id_list.split(",")
print("Deleting Instance IDs:")
for instance_id in instance_ids:
    print(instance_id)
    instance = ec2.describe_instances(
        InstanceIds=[instance_id]
        )['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]
    ec2info = defaultdict()
    tags = instance['Tags']
    name = ""
    for tag in tags:
        if tag["Key"] == "Name":
            name = tag["Value"]
    print("Name = ", name)
```

Produces the following output:

```
Enter an instance ID separated by commas: i-04be74d3a1713ce84
Deleting Instance IDs:
i-04be74d3a1713ce84
Name =  test1
```